# Search particular column value from CSV file using java

Tags: java, csv

I want to search by column value and retrieve that particular row from a csv file using java. Suppose I provide **"ABC123"** than the result should come in this format **"ABC123, SW, Php"**.

Here is the csv file format:

Employee_Id, Designation, Domain

ABC123,        SW,          Php

XYZ456,        SW,          Java

So how do I search any clue. Thanks .

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?

Comment: what help is needed ... do you need source code or direction to start with ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is that you had done in order to achieve this,where exactly you are having bottlenecks etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line with a `BufferedReader` wrapped around a `FileReader`. Stop when you hit a line that [`startsWith`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) the thing you're looking for. Close the reader and return the line.

Edit:
There's no fancy searching or optimising you can do here, unless the CSV file has some sort of order you haven't mentioned. You just have to read each line until you find the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Use OpenCSV to read the CSV file](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read), then find and return the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * returns a string which is comma separate column values for matching row otherwise null. 
 * @param searchColumnIndex
 * @param searchString
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 * 
 */
public String searchCsvLine(int searchColumnIndex, String searchString) throws IOException {
    String resultRow = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.csv"));
    String line;
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        if(values[searchColumnIndex].equals(searchString)) {
            resultRow = line;
            break;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return resultRow;
}
```

In your case the call will be `String result = searchCsvLine(0, "ABC123");`

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Example4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String splitBy = ",";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\\sample1.csv"));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
      System.out.println(b[0]);
    }
    br.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if you added some explanation to describe _why_ it answers the question.